# Exception with Shiro and Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, glassfish, shiro

I'm trying to change a aplication to Maven. 
I'm working with NetBeans and GlassFish 3.1.2.2.
There is a problem that I can't solve. I have been searching and I have not found any solution.
My problem is with Shiro.
The GlassFish console show that:

> Grave: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuration error.  Specified object [anyofroles] with property [loginUrl] without first defining that object's class.  Please first specify the class property first, e.g. myObject = fully_qualified_class_name and then define additional properties. 
>   at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:361)
>   at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:325)

My Shiro versions are the same at the previous project:
* shiro-cas -> 1.2.0
* shiro-core -> 1.3.0
* shiro-web -> 1.3.0

My shiri.ini contains that:

```
[main]
anyofroles.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
# realm to be used
secundaryRealm=com.asesoreslocales.security.SecondaryRealm
anyofroles = com.asesoreslocales.security.AnyRolesAuthorizationFilter
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

[users]

[urls]
/mantenimientos/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/remesas/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/alegaciones/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/notificaciones/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]

/expedientes/expedientes.xhtml = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/expedientes/busquedaExpedientes.xhtml = anyofroles["administrador,editor,consultor"]
```

At the previous project, Shiro worked normally.

Thank for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages says you should first declare the object:

`anyofroles = com.asesoreslocales.security.AnyRolesAuthorizationFilter`

and then define the properties of it:

`anyofroles.loginUrl = /login.xhtml`

Did you try that? Maybe like this:

```
[main]
# realm to be used
secundaryRealm=com.asesoreslocales.security.SecondaryRealm
anyofroles = com.asesoreslocales.security.AnyRolesAuthorizationFilter
anyofroles.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

[users]

[urls]
/mantenimientos/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/remesas/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/alegaciones/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/notificaciones/** = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]

/expedientes/expedientes.xhtml = anyofroles["administrador,editor"]
/expedientes/busquedaExpedientes.xhtml = anyofroles["administrador,editor,consultor"]
```

Comment: It was that... It makes perfect sense but when I tried to fix it I did not think about that. I don't know why at the previous project works normally. Thank you so much!!